# Using multu in MIPS

Tags: mips

So I'm struggling with using `multu` in MIPS
supposedly hi will take the high side of the 64 bit and lo will take the low part but it doesn't happen like that

```
    li  $t0, 98765
    li  $t1, 54321
    
    mult $t0, $t1
    
    mflo $s0
    mfhi $s1
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall
```

What it does is
hi = 1
lo = 1070046269
instead of being 5,365,013,565 as a whole

Comment: `(1 << 32) + 1070046269 == 5365013565`, so it's entirely correct.

Comment: 5,365,013,565 doesn't fit in 32 bits, so if you take `hi` and `lo` as individual 32-bit values you'll never see 5,365,013,565.  If you take them together as a single 64-bit value, they represent that number.

Comment: Or in other words: Multiply `hi` with 4294967296 (2^32) and add `lo`.